# Can ng-repeat take user defined $index increment in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-if

**Pure HTML:**

```
<div class="table-tr museo_sans500">
    <div class="table-td"><a href="javascript:void(0)">fgfbgfbfg</a></div>
    <div class="table-td"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Wtrtrdgdgf</a></div>
    <div class="table-td"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Wayne Rooney</a</div>
    <div class="table-td"><a href="javascript:void(0)">fghgfhgfhgf</a></div>
</div>
<div class="table-tr museo_sans500">
    <div class="table-td"><a href="javascript:void(0)"hgfhgfhfg</a></div>
    <div class="table-td"><a href="javascript:void(0)">asdasdasdas</a></div>
    <div class="table-td"><a href="javascript:void(0)">testsfsdfs</a></div>
    <div class="table-td"><a href="javascript:void(0)">gfhgfhfghgf</a></div>
</div>
```

I need to make it dynamic and I am using Angular JS and PHP.
I already get the data in angular `$scope.teamSquad` and implement it in following way:

```
<div class="table-tr museo_sans500" ng-repeat="(key,squad) in teamSquad">
     <div class="table-td"><a href="javascript:void(0)">{{squad.PlayerName}}</a></div>
</div>
```

But I am having problem in adding `</div><div class="table-tr museo_sans500">` after every more values.

I have already tried `{{key%4==0  ? '</div><div class="table-tr museo_sans500">' : ''}}` but it doesn't work.

I also tried  but result was same.

Comment: what you actually need is nested ng-repeat. The way you are trying right now will never work

Comment: @entre I also tried thinking about a nested ng-repeat logic but still failed.

Comment: can you please us, why it was `in vain`?

Comment: means, I didn't able to build a logic to nested ng-repeat

Comment: would you like to add separate the div section every FOUR players?

Comment: @codeninja yes, i want to make separate div section every four players

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @entre said, you should use nested ng-repeat to accomplish this task

```
 <div class="table-tr museo_sans500" ng-repeat="squadChunk in teamSquad">
   <div class="table-td" ng-repeat="squad in squadChunk"><a href="javascript:void(0)">{{squad.PlayerName}}</div>
</div>
```

Split your array into chunks (size of 4)

```
var _teamSquad = [
{PlayerName: 1},
{PlayerName: 2},
{PlayerName: 3},
{PlayerName: 4},
{PlayerName: 5},
{PlayerName: 6},
{PlayerName: 7},
{PlayerName: 8}
];

$scope.teamSquad = [];

var size = 4;
while (_teamSquad.length > 0)
$scope.teamSquad.push(_teamSquad.splice(0, size));
```

[Complete Solution](http://embed.plnkr.co/FgwOsb04KLwAA5GCF0Dd/preview)